# Fitting truncated normal mixtures in R

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

I have a vector `x`, `lower_bound < x < upper_bound`. I would like to fit a truncated normal mixture distribution to `x`. I can use the package mixtools to fit a normal mixture:

```
library(mixtools)
mix_fit <- normalmixEM(x)
```

but that does not account for the upper and lower bounds. Is there any package in R that fits truncated normal mixtures? Otherwise, I guess I'd have to implement my own EM. So if no packages have this functionality, I'd welcome any good references on implementation details for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct approach to estimating a mixture of two $(a,b)$ truncated Normal distributions
$$f(x;\boldsymbol{\theta})=\varpi_1 \varphi(x;\mu_1,\sigma_1,a,b)+(1-\varpi_1)\varphi(x;\mu_0,\sigma_0,a,b)$$
where
$$\varphi(x;\mu_1,\sigma_1,a,b)=\dfrac{\exp\{-(x-\mu_1)^2/2\sigma_1^2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1[\Phi(\{b-\mu_1\}/\sigma_1)-\Phi(\{a-\mu_1\}/\sigma_1)]}$$
is to use the complete likelihood
$$\prod_{i=1}^n [\varpi_1 \varphi(x_i;\mu_1,\sigma_1,a,b)]^{z_i}[(1-\varpi_1)\varphi(x_i;\mu_0,\sigma_0,a,b)]^{1-z_i}$$
with E target
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[Z_i|x_i,\boldsymbol{\theta}^-]\log [\varpi_1 \varphi(x_i;\mu_1,\sigma_1,a,b)]+\\\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[1-Z_i|x_i,\boldsymbol{\theta}^-]
\log [(1-\varpi_1) \varphi(x_i;\mu_0,\sigma_0,a,b)]
$$
where
$$\mathbb E[Z_i|x_i,\boldsymbol{\theta}]=\dfrac{
\varpi_1 \varphi(x_i;\mu_1,\sigma_1,a,b)}{f(x_i;\boldsymbol{\theta})}$$
which involves in the M step
$$\varpi_1^+ = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[Z_i|x_i,\boldsymbol{\theta}]$$
and
$$(\mu_1^+,\mu_0^+,\sigma_1^+,\sigma_0^+) = 
\arg\max\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[Z_i|x_i,\boldsymbol{\theta}^-]\log \varphi(x_i;\mu_1,\sigma_1,a,b)+\\\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[1-Z_i|x_i,\boldsymbol{\theta}^-]
\log \varphi(x_i;\mu_0,\sigma_0,a,b)
$$
Unfortunately, this optimisation [is not feasible](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06958) in an analytical form.

A potentially interesting alternative is to add to the observed sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ a latent sample
$$(Y_1,\ldots,Y_{N_1},W_1,\ldots,W_{N_2})$$ such that

1. the $Y_i$'s are from the mixture truncated to $(-\infty,a)$
2. the $W_j$'s are from the mixture truncated to $(b,\infty)$
3. $N_1\sim\mathcal B(n/\{F(b;\boldsymbol{\theta})-F(a;\boldsymbol{\theta})\},F(a;\boldsymbol{\theta}))$
4. $N_2\sim\mathcal B(n/\{F(b;\boldsymbol{\theta})-F(a;\boldsymbol{\theta})\},1-F(b;\boldsymbol{\theta}))$

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer. I'm trying to implement it, and it seems to work well in terms of finding the correct mixtures. However, the log-likelihood does not seem to be monotonically increasing. I have a couple of follow up questions:

1) If implemented correctly, should I be getting a monotonically increasing log-likelihood?
2) I am adding the latent sample after the M-step of the EM algorithm. Is this OK?
3) When estimating the log-likelihood, should I use only the observed sample?

Comment: 1) If you generate all four steps, this is Monte Carlo EM and hence there is no reason for the observed likelihood to increase. 2) On principle the latent sample should be used in the E-step, exactly or via a Monte-Carlo approximation. 3) The E step is using the completed likelihood, with all latent variables.